# Windows 10 IoT - DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync() returns empty collection

Tags: raspberry-pi, accelerometer, i2c, windows-10-iot-core, gyroscope

I'm trying to use a MPU-6050 (GY-521) sensor with my Raspberry Pi 3 and Windows 10 IoT. I'm following [this example](https://www.hackster.io/graham_chow/mpu-6050-for-windows-iot-d67793) on Hackster, but the following line

```
DeviceInformationCollection collection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
```

returns an empty collection. I am using Microsoft Lightning provider.

This is the `aqs` string value which is obtained via `I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector()` :

```
System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:="{A11EE3C6-8421-4202-A3E7-B91FF90188E4}" AND System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DMAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/lightningproviders) and the inbox drivers are mutually exclusive. The default (inbox) I2C as well as the SPI and GPIO drivers are disabled when DMAP driver is enabled through the device portal.So, the code above in your post will not work. Please use following code instead.

```
        if (LightningProvider.IsLightningEnabled)
        {
            LowLevelDevicesController.DefaultProvider = LightningProvider.GetAggregateProvider();
        }

        I2cController controller = await I2cController.GetDefaultAsync();
```